# Is there any way to increase the YouTube API v3 Quota Limits?

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to (paid or unpaid) to increase the 5,000,000 units/day quota limit imposed when using version 3 of the YouTube API?

I have read that a video upload alone uses 16,000 units - this equates to only ~312 videos a day.

I have signed up for 'billing' but still don't get an option to increase from the "courtesy limit" of 5 million.

Comment: Dear Friend , how you get 5.000.000 units/day quota ? I have only 10.000.

Comment: @PetrosMosoyan that was in 2013, it changed since, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580411/1515819

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an elaborate [form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) for applying for higher quota.

It is linked in the developer console for example at: `http://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube-json.googleapis.com/quotas?project=YOURPROJECTID`

The form starts off with some statements:

> This Application will ask you detailed questions about:
>
> (i) your business,  (ii) your use of each YouTube API (current and
>   proposed use, as applicable), and  (iii) each of your website or
>   software application that uses or will use YouTube API(s) (each an
>   “API Client”).
>
> This application also requires you to submit screenshots and design
>   documents relating to your API Client(s) and your use of YouTube
>   API(s). If you do not have these ready, please apply once these are
>   available.
>
> We will strive to respond to your application as soon as possible,
>   provided that, all required supporting materials are submitted and
>   sufficient, and all questions are thoroughly answered.
>
> **Note: Please do not apply for more quota unless you are actually close to hitting your current limit.**

Comment: I got a 'The API "youtube-json.googleapis.com" doesn't exist' error when I follow the link

Comment: Did you have any luck after filling this out? I just did.

Comment: @lustig how many additional quota units were you able to get after submitting the form?

Comment: @abe It took about 4 months for them to respond, but I think I have 500,000 units. Would have to confirm. It's a healthy amount, but you can still run into it with a busy enough application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Form but they do not approve extra quota at the moment. Maybe in the future. Best would be to contact your Google Account Manager (If you have one assigned)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDdnNVF3aGpuLXV1R2V2Nzg3QjJoZWc6MQ