# Is quota limit 1M or 50M for YouTube API v3 ?

Tags: youtube-api

The [website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) says the quota limit is 1M whereas the Google+ [post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+YouTubeDev/posts/iPEwJzKDgq9) clearly mentions the quota is increased to 50M. How do i get 50M as daily quota?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the newly default quota. As can be seen in the documentation you provided:

> Note that projects that had enabled the YouTube Data API before April 20, 2016, have a different default quota for that API.

If you just recently enabled the API, then it is expected that you have the 1M limit. If you need more than 1M quota, you can send in a [request for higher quota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496800/4625829).

See more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580411/4625829).

Comment: For the record, as of January 11, 2019, the default quota for newly enabled YouTube Data API applications is only 10 000 units/day. Boo...

Comment: @TomaszCz Feel free to submit an edit answer request (just make sure to include the documentation for your source) and I'll approve it. Cheers!

Comment: @AL. Sorry to bother you here. I'm the dev behind YT Tracker, an iOS App that relies on the YouTube Data API. My quota got dropped to 0 queries per day after I requested additional quota when I started hitting the allocated limit (320k per day). It appears the YouTube API Services team think I'm violating the 'Playback Integrity' policy but I do not embed videos in my app so this is clearly a mistake. My app has thousands of DAU and it's now failing in production. Do you think you could help?

Comment: Hi @EdouardBarbier Sorry to hear about that. It's been a while since I've interacted with the Youtube APIs and services. However, if you believe that there is no such violation is happening, then I would getting back to the YouTube API support team directly, asking for a re-evaluation while providing proof that there is no violation whatsoever.

Comment: @EdouardBarbier was just curious if you ever got it sorted out and got your API limit back up? My web app failed due to these very low API limits.