# youtube data api pricing

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I increase daily limit of Youtube data API v3? Youtube Data API's Daily limit is 1M units. Video search API cost is 100 units. So 10K users searching at same time my unit usage will be reach the limit.

Thank you.

Comment: this has been answered in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154572/is-there-any-way-to-increase-the-youtube-api-v3-quota-limits)

Comment: Thank you. I got it my answer in your link.