# How to Cross the 1000 Results Limit of youtube data API?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I need all video's ID between X to Y dates of specific subject. I used YouTube data API v3 and every thing was OK, until it returned empty item after 1000 result. I searched about this issue and figured out it's API limitation!!! Does anyone have any solution?
If it helps I code in python.I did test in php too and same result. It doesn't depend on languages.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to increase the YouTube API v3 Quota Limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154572/is-there-any-way-to-increase-the-youtube-api-v3-quota-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Just split your date range into multiple requests, so each request < result limit.

Comment: I tried it and at last total result was much less.  i split date then add each result numbers, but total was huge different with the whole date.