# Magento 2 youtube video quota exceeded

Tags: youtube-api, quota, magento-2.3

I am trying to add a brand new youtube video (to our Magento 2 website) we just uploaded and am already receiving the "quota exceeded" response from the youtube api.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need more quota. For that, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496800/4092887). These entries [(1)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161305379) [(2)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166163968) in issue tracker reffers to the same form to apply for more quota.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [YouTube Data API official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=en#quota):

> **Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota
> by completing the [Quota extension request form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) for YouTube API
> Services**.

Comment: the video I am trying to link is brand new and in the API reporting area no quota has been used on it yet

Comment: @user2813308004 how big the video is?, maybe it exceeds your quota. If you consider this is a problem, please use Issue Tracker. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960647/4092887) for more information.