# YouTube live streaming API limit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is there a limit to how much you can stream via YouTube live streaming API? Is there pricing for large scale usage?

I noticed that there is quota given for the YouTube Data API

[Youtube API Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568405/youtube-api-limitations)

https://google-developers.appspot.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost?hl=fr-BE

But how about live-streaming API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube Live Streaming API seems to be part of the YouTube Data API (at least, in order to use it you need to enable the YouTube Data API as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)). I assume that this means the Live Streaming API uses the same quota from the Data API. As far as bandwidth or how much you can stream goes, I do not think there are limitations, but as per any other Google API, there are limitations on how many times you can call the API. The first link you provided provided is asking about this. The second link you provided simply calculates how much of said quota is consumed when different requests are made. I believe there are no costs involved; when you reach your quota limit, you simply can no longer make more requests to the API until your quota is refreshed. For many of Google's APIs you can request for more quota, but I do not see it for any of the YouTube APIs, so that may not be an option.

Comment: Thanks! We are making this for a client. If for some reason the site is such a boom, is there a possibility that we can sign some sort of deal with YouTube for additional quota? I just want to know what we can promise to the client.