# What is the quota limit when using YouTube Live Streaming API in terms on unit cost?

Tags: youtube-api

The **[YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)** has a great documentation regarding unit cost for each properties being retrieved. It even has a **[Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)** developers can use. However, the **YouTube Live Streaming API** does not seem to list the unit cost. ***Does anyone know how quota are computed per property in YouTube Live Streaming API?***

For listing, these are the properties (part) that are use in YouTube Live Streaming API:

- id (from YouTube Data API has a unit cost of 0)
- snippet (from YouTube Data API has a unit cost of 1 or 2)
- contentDetails (from YouTube Data API has a unit cost of 2)
- status (from YouTube Data API has a unit cost of 2)
- *cdn (not listed in YouTube Data API)*

And for a list call, usually has a unit cost of 1 except for *search* which has a unit cost of 100 by default regardless of the properties being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Resources section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) of Youtube Live Streaming API, it says that:

> all of these resources are actually defined as part of either the
>   YouTube Data API or the YouTube Content ID API. However, the
>   liveBroadcast, liveStream, and liveCuepoint resources are only used to
>   create and manage live events.

So that means Youtube Live Streaming API's quotas are basically derived from Youtube Data API and Youtube Content ID API. Hence, they are the same. You can use the Quota Calculator here just by looking up the corresponding resources mentioned in the Youtube Live Streaming API.

Found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924237/youtube-live-streaming-api-limit), I think it's saying the same thing as well.

Comment: i tried 19x live stream today, then it got error message: `Error 403: Request is not authorized, insufficientLivePermissions`