# Can i make trivia HQ like game using youtube streaming api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

What I need is a real-time streaming server I'm wondering if I can use YouTube streaming API for Streaming and Broadcasting on my custom created app? If yes, then what is the cost of youtube streaming? Is there a limit to how much you can stream via YouTube live streaming API? Is there pricing for large scale usage? Youtube streaming API for broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started#resources), a resource is an individual data entity with a unique identifier. Technically, all of these resources are actually defined as part of either the YouTube Data API or the YouTube Content ID API.

Also based from this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924237/youtube-live-streaming-api-limit),

> The YouTube Live Streaming API seems to be part of the YouTube Data API (at least, in order to use it you need to enable the YouTube Data API as noted here). I assume that this means the Live Streaming API uses the same quota from the Data API. As far as bandwidth or how much you can stream goes, I do not think there are limitations, but as per any other Google API, there are limitations on how many times you can call the API. The first link you provided provided is asking about this. The second link you provided simply calculates how much of said quota is consumed when different requests are made. I believe there are no costs involved; when you reach your quota limit, you simply can no longer make more requests to the API until your quota is refreshed. For many of Google's APIs you can request for more quota, but I do not see it for any of the YouTube APIs, so that may not be an option.

There is a [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) which lets you estimate the quota cost for an API query. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.