# Are there limits for retrieving text from Youtube? Can I get content of comments?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am student and I am building Project that can retrieve textual features from YouTube videos using YouTube API.

Are there limits to search for videos and retrieve its information per day?

Can I retrieve all comments of each video or just its number?

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Please, any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

## Are there limitations for getting data from YouTube?

Yes, see the quota usage section in [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

One of the examples of what can be done per day might be helpful for your case:

> if you have a daily quota of 1,000,000 units, your application could have [...] the following approximate limits:
>
> - 200,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.

More thorough answer: [Youtube API Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568405/youtube-api-limitations)

## Getting YouTube video comments

`statistics.commentCount` from [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) only gives you the amount.

[`commentThreads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads) will give you the comments, see `get_comments` in the [Python examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python)

Answer (score 0):

[*CommentThreads*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads)

> A **`commentThread`** resource contains information about a YouTube comment thread, which comprises a top-level comment and replies, if any exist, to that comment. A **`commentThread`** resource can represent comments about either a video or a channel.

HTTP request

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments

You might want to check CommentThreads: list, this will get all comment from Youtube video / channel.

> Returns a list of comment threads that match the API request parameters.

You can check the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#examples), it demonstrates how to use the following API methods to create and manage top-level comments.

Hope it helps!