# How does social blade generate the Live Subscriber Count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How does Socialblade generate the [live subscriber count](https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/ricegum/realtime) with the youtube api?

It updates every second for each channel. Wouldn't that easily exceed the rate limit?

From their [app store description](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/live-sub-count-social-blade/id1208869005?mt=8), they state they're pulling from the youtube api:

```
View your favorite YouTubers live sub counter 
and get real-time updates every second direct from YouTube's API. 
No more having to wait hours for the number on your channel to update!
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exceed their ratelimit.

It has a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) of 1 point. [You can use 30,000 quota units/second/user and 1,000,000 per day. 50M if your application was made before April 20, 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580411/8817940).

Comment: But they're doing this for thousands of channels. With 50M daily quota at 1 point per second, you could only do this for 578 users. `50000000/86400=578` 86400 is seconds in a day for one channel.

Comment: @loop I highly doubt SocialBlade needs to worry about 578 concurrent users that stay for 24 hours. Most people on there are there for a few minutes at most.

Comment: @loop ! What is/are the endpoint they are using to grab this info? Are all these data available for free?