# YouTube V3 API quote exceeded daily limit is only 10k

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am getting error messages after 4 video upload through API.
I have created a new project in console and I only have 10 000 daily quote 
although "Queries per 100 seconds per user" is 300 000 so I don't get it why my daily limit is so low... Do you have the same quote if you create a project now?
I am getting the below error messages what could be the issue?

> The service youtube has thrown an exception:
>   Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The
>   request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota. [403] Errors [
>           Message[The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).]
>   Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExceeded] Domain[youtube.quota] ]
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__25.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.d__70.MoveNext()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube API Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568405/youtube-api-limitations)

Comment: I don't think it's actually a duplicate to the posted SO question.  I believe the issue is not authenticating properly so it uses the "default" credentials that are extremely limited.  Are you sure you're authenticating your API request properly?

Comment: Yes I use oAuth authentication and I see the 10 000 daily quote on my dashboard too

Comment: is there any alternatives for that YouTube API or other Service ? i am also not getting response.

Answer (score 2):

i have the exact same issue as you, only 10k daily quota. pretty sure the default used to be a lot higher, like 1 million or something

i found this form you can use to request an quota increase, but 10k seems laughably low so i dont think we should have to request a increase (also it ask for all kinds of info like your a company)

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/formResponse

Comment: I filled that form already but no surprise I got no answer... just what I have expected from google customer service...

Comment: I have the same issue. 10,000 is unusable. Even after enabling billing and submitting the exemption form, I'm still stuck at 10K. It's not even enough for dev and test.

Comment: is there any alternatives for that YouTube API or other Service ? i am also not getting response.

Comment: Did any of you ever get a response from Google? 10k limit is ridiculous.