# How much google charges for increasing quota of YouTube Data API up to 10M units or 50M units

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wants to increase the quota limit for YouTube Data API, currently they are providing only 10K units , but i wants at least of 10M units for my project. So how google charge for units, and any estimated figure to know how much they may charge to increase the quota?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568405/youtube-api-limitations

Comment: Maranatha, It was helpful to know the way to get extra quota, but there were no any info related pricing .. I wants to know that what price I have to pay to get 10M units quota..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not google support.  OP should request an extension and wait for Google to respond and ask them.

Comment: There is no official pricing guiltiness for the YouTube API you need to talk to Google